# How to create new column if previous column value is Datetime using R programming

Tags: r, if-statement

How to check if a column has a DateTime value(some rows are strings) and if so, it should display the next row as a separate column using R programming

```
     **Column1**
30-01-2020 21:03:34
please check the date
30/1/2020 21:05:11
Data is safe
Database error


**Expected Output**

     **Column 1**                   **Column 2**
30/2/2020 21:03:34             please check the date
please check the date                    NA  
30/2/2020 21:05:11                  Data is safe
Data is safe                             NA    
Database error                           NA
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mean for incorrect and impossible dates like 30feb, it should display value from next row? What if non-date or valid date format? NA for both? For next row value you can use `lead` function

Comment: Why it is tagged in Tableau?

Comment: Thanks, Anil for the heads up, it was 30th Jan and not 30th Feb. I have tagged tableau for code related to the calculation field if any.

Comment: Means, you want to do the same in tableau also? Or in any one is sufficient. Rolling functions in Tableau depend on views i.e. it may be difficult to hard code the values like programming languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work, as Anil pointed out, dates are not exactly dates (Feb 30), so I've used regex:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(column2 = case_when(str_detect(Column1, '[0-9]{1,2}\\/\\d\\/\\d{4}.*') ~ lead(Column1), TRUE ~ NA_character_))
                Column1               column2
1    30/2/2020 21:03:34 please check the date
2 please check the date                  <NA>
3    30/2/2020 21:05:11          Data is safe
4          Data is safe                  <NA>
5        Database error                  <NA>
```

Data used:

```
df <- structure(list(Column1 = c("30/2/2020 21:03:34", "please check the date", 
"30/2/2020 21:05:11", "Data is safe", "Database error")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Updated answer:

```
df %>% mutate(column2 = case_when(str_detect(Column1, '[0-9]{1,2}\\/\\d\\/\\d{4}.*') ~ lead(Column1), TRUE ~ NA_character_))
                                          Column1               column2
1 30/2/2020 21:03:34-This date is updated by John please check the date
2                           please check the date                  <NA>
3                              30/2/2020 21:05:11          Data is safe
4                                    Data is safe                  <NA>
5                                  Database error                  <NA>
```

New update:

```
df %>% mutate(column2 = case_when(str_detect(Column1, '[0-9]{1,2}[\\/-]\\d{1,2}[\\/-]\\d{4}.*') ~ lead(Column1), TRUE ~ NA_character_))
                                          Column1               column2
1 30/1/2020 21:03:34-This date is updated by John please check the date
2                           please check the date                  <NA>
3                             30-01-2020 21:03:34          Data is safe
4                                    Data is safe                  <NA>
5                                  Database error                  <NA>
```

Comment: Hi Karthik, the dates are exactly in DateTime format as mentioned in my sample dataset. When I tried the above code it gives me NA for all rows in column 2 even if it has datetime in column 1.

Comment: @Akshi, Not sure why that's happening, I have used the data you shared. Have again shared it in my answer, Can you check if there's a difference in the data used here and your actual data.

Comment: In column 1 along with DateTime it also includes some strings appended to it, will that create a  difference? For example, "30/1/2020 21:03:34-This date is updated by John"

Comment: @Akshi, it still works for me: have updated my answer. Can you share the data as it is? using dput, top 10-15 rows.

Comment: I have added an image of the sample dataset for reference...

Comment: Now that I also get the below error    Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `column1`.
x must be a `factor` object, not a character vector.

Comment: Hi, how to change the regex ('[0-9]{1,2}\\/\\d\\/\\d{4}.*')for the below format of DateTime
30-01-2020 21:03:34 instead of 30/2/2020 21:03:34

Comment: @Akshi, have updated my answer, have added a new row with that pattern.

Comment: @Akshi, if it did work for you, can you please accept the answer by clicking tick symbol next to the answer.

Comment: I am able to retrieve a few data and others with format 2020-06-30 11:11:46 gives me NA. Any changes to be done in regex?
Hope this can be sorted out !!

Comment: tried changing the regex pattern but no luck, any suggestions or solutions for this?